# How to load contacts to listview correct?

Tags: android, listview, android-contentprovider

I am trying to load contacts to my listview but Every time(not only this project) Cursor is loading wrong.Listview has a checkbox that user select from the list and all values go to the second activity.In the other hand; My application doesn't recognize wrong items and Selected items don"t match its phone numbers. How can I fix this repeating?

Note: I tried

```
if (!listtearama.contains(phonenumber)){         
   listtearama.add(phonenumber);
}
```

It doesn't work.

[image]

That"s why my application is loading wrong.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 ArrayList<String> selectedlist = new ArrayList<>();
    ListView chosinglist;
    Button kaydet;

    ArrayList<String> selectedlistarama = new ArrayList<>();
     ArrayList<String> listte = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> listtearama = new ArrayList<>();
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



         chosinglist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chosing);
                chosinglist.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

                getNumber(this.getContentResolver());



            }

            private void getNumber(ContentResolver contentResolver) {
                Cursor phones = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

                if (phones != null && phones.getCount() > 0) {
                    //move to the first element, the cursor might be at an invalid location
                    phones.moveToFirst();
                    do {

                        String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        String phonenumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                        System.out.println(".................." + phonenumber);



                            listte.add(name);



                            listtearama.add(phonenumber);


                    } while (phones.moveToNext());
                    phones.close();// close cursor
                }




                final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.checkrow,
                        R.id.checkedTextView2, listte);


                kaydet.setEnabled(false);

     chosinglist.setAdapter(adapter);

            chosinglist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 
String selecteditem = (String) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);

   String aramakicinliste = listtearama.get(position);



                if (selectedlistarama.contains(aramakicinliste)) {
                    selectedlistarama.remove(aramakicinliste);
                } else
                    selectedlistarama.add(aramakicinliste);


                if (selectedlist.contains(selecteditem)) {
                    selectedlist.remove(selecteditem);

                } else selectedlist.add(selecteditem);

}
```

Comment: Did you try notifyDataSetChanged() method for adapter ?

Comment: Yes , İ tried now.It doesn"t work in first activity.

Comment: How are you updating your adapter? usually the flow is: First you update an ArrayList, then use that ArrayList to update your Adapter, and then set the Adapter to your ListView. notifyDataSetChanged() is used, if there is any change in the elements of Arraylist, Adapter will get notified and will update the ListView.

Comment: I don"t need to update adapter again for passing to second activity.User"s only select from listview.There is no more update because selected items go to my database.Just I want to load listview rightly.I am editting my question now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a flag for a selected item in your adapter.

Just Follow the changes in you Adapter class.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if ((convertView == null) || (convertView.getTag() == null)) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
        context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    convertView.setTag(holder);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: I am not use baseadapter.I am using arrayadapter.These methods using at base adapter.